# Passing raw Markdown text to Jade

Tags: node.js, markdown, express, pug

I'm playing around with my first Node.js [Express](http://expressjs.com/) application, and as every programmer knows, the first thing you should build when testing out a new framework is a blog! Anyway, I'd like to write the articles in Markdown and then render it in the view. I saw that Jade allows for this to be done inside the view itself, using filters, but I can't get that working.

To simplify the situation, here's an example of what I'm talking about.

```
//app.js
res.render("article", {
    md : "Hello World!\n\n*Woo*"
});

//article.jade
section
    :markdown
        #{md}
```

But, that outputs this: `<section><h1>{md}</h1></section>`... it isn't substituting in the variables I've passed to it.

Then I tried this:

```
//article.jade
section
    :markdown
        !{md}
```

And the output is this:

```
<section><p>Hello World!

*Woo*</p></section>
```

So, now it's not parsing the markdown!

I have been able to get this to work by parsing the markdown in the `app.js` file and then passing the HTML to the view to display, but I don't know, that seems a bit messier.

Is there a way to pass variables into Jade filters?

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this?

Comment: Just to supplement as to why this doesn't work out of the box, Filters are run at compile time, meaning they cannot support dynamic content. As says the warning on this page: http://jade-lang.com/reference/filters/

Answer (score 20):

You can do this with a function passed in to jade from node:

```
var md = require("node-markdown").Markdown;
```

Then pass it into the view as a local:

```
res.render('view', { md:md, markdownContent:data });
```

Then render it in the jade view by calling the function:

```
!= md(markdownContent)
```

Answer (score 15):

The node module `node-markdown` is deprecated. The [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) is advanced new version. You can try like this

```
var md = require('marked');
```

Inside your router

```
res.render('template', { md: md });
```

Inside your jade template

```
div!= md(note.string)
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't think jade can do this out of the box.  One way to accomplish it that might feel slightly cleaner than pre-rendering the markdown is to create a helper function called `markdown` that takes a markdown string and returns HTML.  Then you could do something like

```
section
    != markdown(md)
```

The markdown function should be included in the `locals` data when you render the jade template and can directly use a markdown library to convert the markdown syntax to HTML.

Comment: great way to work around this issue... Has anyone tried benchmarking for impact?

Comment: So, they've decided to implement a dedicated `:markdown` filter but didn't choose to provide a mechanism of loading external Markdown files into this filter? ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Scalate's Jade support](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/jade.html) you can enter:

```
section
    :&markdown
        #{md}
```

You can also import external files with:

```
section
    :&markdown
        #{include("MyFile.md")}
```

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. I did upvote it, because you got me so excited. But with further research I could not find any Node js Scala implementations. Now that syntax is awesome, and I like the idea, but I do not think its time has come, yet...

Comment: It was probably not the answer you were looking for as it runs under Scala on the JVM not under node.js, but this answer is valid if you are using the Jade support of Scalate and the link at the top of my answer takes you to the documentation about this.