# jade filter :markdown for an object with a

Tags: markdown, pug

I have an object from the database with some markdown markup I would like to render with jade. But how? When I apply the :markdown filter I can't use the object as object anymore, but it get's treated as text.

I started here:

```
p
   :markdown
      entry.content
```

Which renders to plain:

```
entry.content
```

So I tried putting = and - in front or wrapping #{} arround it. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters are compile-time, so if you want to run a markdown filter on a run-time variable, you'll have to render the markdown yourself and pass it to your jade view:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/express-js/8H4HNcoeekk

Answer (score 3):

I found a simple way of doing this, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21050011/5418136). It uses [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) library so first install it.

```
$ npm install marked --save
```

In router page

```
var markdown = require('marked');
var text = '**new text**';
res.render('template', {text:text, markdown:markdown});
```

In template.jade, try any of following lines

```
!= markdown(text);
p!= markdown(text);
```

This is cleanest way of implementing dynamic filters for markdown, in my opinion.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. From [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks. i'm planning to expand the answer. give me few minutes.

Comment: @morales u can review the answer now :-)